# Clicking logout and/or shutdown does nothing

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does nothing happen when I click “Shutdown” from the “shutdown…” dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53713/why-does-nothing-happen-when-i-click-shutdown-from-the-shutdown-dialog)

As a newbie to Ubuntu 11.10, recently I am facing a problem where if I click either logout or shutdown option(s), it does nothing. I mean absolutely nothing. Though hibernate option is working normally. Kindly help me out here friends so that I can properly logout/shutdown my laptop.

Comment: It must be a bug that affects the spicific laptop.
What's your model?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to the core problem, but to shutdown/restart open a terminal (open the Dash home menu and in the search box type `terminal` and a link will appear) and then enter the command

```
sudo poweroff
```

to shut the computer down, or

```
sudo reboot
```

to restart it. These commands will prompt you for your password before proceeding.